# How to add or remove using ID instead of classes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I replace the the class highlight with an id instead, so when I click outside of the products, it doesn't highlight that area?

I included the window.onload section with what I want to do, however I don't know how to change the class highlight into id. I can't think of an easier way than changing the class and then using the window.onload.

```js
let overlay;
document.querySelectorAll('.product').forEach(function(path) {
  path.onclick = chooseProduct;
})

function chooseProduct(e) {
  if (overlay) overlay.classList.remove('highlight')
  overlay = e.target
  overlay.classList.add('highlight')
}

//What I want to add to the highlight class using id to remove black border when click outside of the products

// window.onload = function(){
//   var hide = document.getElementById('?');
//   document.onclick = function(e){
//     if(e.target.id !== '?'){
//       hide.style.display = 'none';
//     }
//   };
// };


var el = document.getElementsByClassName("color");
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].onclick = changeColor;
}

function changeColor(e) {
  let hex = e.target.getAttribute("data-hex");
  if (overlay) overlay.style.fill = hex;
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#product-svg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

path {
  fill: #CCCCCC;
}

#background-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.colors {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 2em;
  right: 2em;
  z-index: 3;
}

.color {
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.highlight {
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <svg id="product-svg" viewBox="0 0 744 1074">
      <path class="product" d="M51 207.5L51 348L686 348L686 67L51 67L51 207.5Z" />
      <path class="product" d="M51 544.5L51 685L686 685L686 404L51 404L51 544.5Z" />
      <path class="product" d="M51 883.5L51 1024L686 1024L686 743L51 743L51 883.5Z" />
    </svg>
  <img id="background-image" src="boxes.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div class="colors">
  <div class="color" style="background-color: #ff0000" data-hex="#ff0000"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color: #ffff33" data-hex="#ffff33"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color: #3399ff" data-hex="#3399ff"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is working as expected, except the part which you have mentioned in the question which highlight style of the selected product is not removed when you clicked outside the product.

In order to do that, simply I have added an Event Listener (`removeHighlight()`) by `document.onclick = removeHighlight;` to the whole `document` on `click` event. So whenever you click on anywhere in the DOM, that event listener will be triggered. What I'm do inside EventListener function is removing the class `highlight` from all products if and only if the click event was not triggered by clicking on either products or colours. Additionally I'm setting the `overlay=null` in order to remove the reference of the previously selected product, then clicking on colors won't fill the previously selected product with selected color if same conditions met and until you click again on a product.

```js
let overlay;
document.querySelectorAll('.product').forEach(function(path) {
  path.onclick = chooseProduct;
})

function chooseProduct(e) {
  if (overlay) overlay.classList.remove('highlight')
  overlay = e.target
  overlay.classList.add('highlight')
}

var removeHighlight = function(e) { 
    var products = document.querySelectorAll('.product');
   
    if(!e.target.classList.contains('product') && !e.target.classList.contains('color')){
        overlay = null;
        document.querySelectorAll('.product').forEach(function(prod){
            prod.classList.remove('highlight');
        });
    }
}

document.onclick = removeHighlight; 


var el = document.getElementsByClassName("color");
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].onclick = changeColor;
}

function changeColor(e) {
  let hex = e.target.getAttribute("data-hex");
  if (overlay) overlay.style.fill = hex;
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#product-svg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

path {
  fill: #CCCCCC;
}

#background-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.colors {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 2em;
  right: 2em;
  z-index: 3;
}

.color {
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.highlight {
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <svg id="product-svg" viewBox="0 0 744 1074">
      <path class="product" d="M51 207.5L51 348L686 348L686 67L51 67L51 207.5Z" />
      <path class="product" d="M51 544.5L51 685L686 685L686 404L51 404L51 544.5Z" />
      <path class="product" d="M51 883.5L51 1024L686 1024L686 743L51 743L51 883.5Z" />
    </svg>
  <img id="background-image" src="boxes.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div class="colors">
  <div class="color" style="background-color: #ff0000" data-hex="#ff0000"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color: #ffff33" data-hex="#ffff33"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color: #3399ff" data-hex="#3399ff"></div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9h0pk2uo/)

Comment: Hope you don't mind, but can you explain a bit more about the code please, so I can learn and understand. Thanks.

Comment: @luck8 Sure. I have edited my answer and added an explanation in there.

Answer (score 1):

When a behavior is a result of a click event occurring anywhere but the tags meant to be clicked, it's most effective to register the `document` Object as the click event listener and control all clicks by [Event Delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

1. register the `document` Object as the click event listener

   ```
   document.onclick = selectPath;
   ```
2. the click event handler is `selectPath(e)`

   1. collect all `.product` into a NodeList

      ```
      const paths = document.querySelectorAll('.product');
      ```
   2. if the user clicked any `.product` remove `.highlight` class from all `.product` and then add `.highlight` class to the `.product` user clicked

      ```
      if (e.target.matches('.product')) {
        paths.forEach(path => path.classList.remove('highlight'));
        e.target.classList.add('highlight');
      ```
   3. but if the user clicked any `.color`, then get it's `[data-hex]` value, and fill `.highlight` with the hex color if it exists (re: `.highlight`)

      ```
      else if (e.target.matches('.color')) {
        let hex = e.target.dataset.hex;
        let selected = document.querySelector('.highlight');
        if (selected) selected.style.fill = hex;
      ```
   4. otherwise just remove the `.highlight` class if it exists.

      ```
      paths.forEach(path => path.classList.remove('highlight'));
      ```

```js
document.onclick = selectPath;

function selectPath(e) {
  const paths = document.querySelectorAll('.product');

  if (e.target.matches('.product')) {
    paths.forEach(path => path.classList.remove('highlight'));
    e.target.classList.add('highlight');
  } else if (e.target.matches('.color')) {
    let hex = e.target.dataset.hex;
    let selected = document.querySelector('.highlight');
    if (selected) selected.style.fill = hex;
  } else {
    paths.forEach(path => path.classList.remove('highlight'));
  }
};
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.svg {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

path {
  fill: #CCCCCC;
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.circles {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 2em;
  right: 2em;
  z-index: 3;
}

.color {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.highlight {
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <svg class="svg" viewBox="0 0 744 1074">
      <path class="product" d="M51 207.5L51 348L686 348L686 67L51 67L51 207.5Z" />
      <path class="product" d="M51 544.5L51 685L686 685L686 404L51 404L51 544.5Z" />
      <path class="product" d="M51 883.5L51 1024L686 1024L686 743L51 743L51 883.5Z" />
    </svg>
  <img class="background" src="boxes.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div class="circles">
  <div class="color" style="background-color: #ff0000" data-hex="#ff0000"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color: #ffff33" data-hex="#ffff33"></div>
  <div class="color" style="background-color: #3399ff" data-hex="#3399ff"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting "highlight" class only for products so you don't need id for what you are going to do.

you can just check if element which you clicked on has "product" class then first you remove all "highlight" classes and then add it to clicked product. If element doesn't have a "product" class then you just remove all "highlight" classes.

```
 window.onload = function(){
   document.onclick = function(e){
     if(e.target.classList.contains("product")){
       resetClass()
       e.target.classList.add("highlight")
     }else{
         resetClass()
     }
   };
 };



 function resetClass(){
   document.querySelectorAll(".highlight").forEach(item => {
         item.classList.remove("highlight")
   })
 }
```